# WPF Key.Enter - what characters does it introduce?

Tags: c#, wpf, enter

I want to know if pressing Enter from the keyboard in a WPF `TextBox` which has `AcceptsReturn="true"` will always put in `\r\n` or is it system dependent?

Is it equal to `System.Environment.NewLine` ?

How do I get these characters programmatically?

I want something like `string enter = Key.Enter.toSomething()...` that will end up with something like `\r\n` or `\n`.

`string enter = Convert.ToString(Key.Enter)` will just give me `"Return"` and other than that conversion there is the possibility to get an `int` value which is `6`, which I can't interpret (or should I be able to?).

Are there any issues I need to consider like the ones mentioned here:
 http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/asills/archive/2010/10/09/tip-silverlight-textbox-uses-r-for-new-lines-not-environment-newline.aspx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be dependent [upon the environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As noted by Microsoft `\r\n` for Windows.

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Comment: so what you're saying is that I can safely presume that `Enter` will always add a `System.Environment.NewLine` ? (as mentioned in the article cited above, it is not always true - aparently not in Silverlight TextBoxes). But is it true for WPF ?

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one, but please check the edit to my comment, the one about Silverlight, since I was adding it while you were answering back.

Comment: @claudiaalexa, yes, for Silverlight you will need to look specifically for `\r` and normalize those to `\r\n` if necessary.